# How to Handle Any Mouse Select Event WPF TreeView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I'm using a treeview control that will be interacted by mouse clicks in wpf project. My treeview has a hierarchical template that gets data from datacontext.

```
    <TreeView x:Name="bolumler" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Margin="-282,7,618,206" Grid.RowSpan="3">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" DataType="{x:Type local:SectionEntity}">
                <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Text}"/>                    
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>        
    </TreeView>
```

It shows the hierarchical data in wpf treeview control properly. But I can't bind mouse click events. It doesn't handle any event. Please can you present any stable example for mouse events in wpf treeview with hierarchical template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Textblock element simply inside item template. After that you can access SelectedItemChanged event on treeview easily.

```
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" DataType="{x:Type local:SectionEntity}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"></TextBlock>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

use SelectedItemChanged event in TreeView:

```
<TreeView Name="trvParameters" SelectedItemChanged="trvParameters_SelectedItemChanged">
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Test}">
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Event handler:

```
private void trvParameters_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    // e.NewValue contains selected item
}
```